# How to find the probability of at least two successes or failures in a Bernoulli trial?

Tags: probability

(1) At least 2 successes in 8 trials with p = 0.2 Which I got correct with .49668352

**(2) At least 2 failures in 5 trials with p = 0.25** This is the one I am have trouble understanding

I am having trouble understanding what to do when it says "At least" instead of it being a constant number of success/failure. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

"At least" means "At least". In a) you have to calculate the probability, that you have 2,3,4,5,6,7 **or** 8 successes. You can calculate the probabilities for each case and sum the results up.

A better way is to take the converse probability. $P(X\geq 2)=1-P(X=1)-P(X=0)$

Thus you have to calculate the probabilities, that you have no success and that you have one success. Then subtract them from 1.